# Textbox loses CSS style when type=password is applied

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and using the following code to style my Login page. When I leave the code as-is everything works great but I want to set the type to password for the password box so it does not show up as normal text. As soon as I set the type to password the CSS style is no longer applied to the password textbox.

```css
.content input[type=text], .content input[type=password] {
  height: 30px;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 2.5vh;
  margin-left: 4.5vw;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.content input[type=submit] {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 7vw;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: black;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content input[placeholder] {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h2>Sign In</h2>
  <input name="username" type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" /><br />
  <input name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" Type="password" /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: _“Here is my aspx code:”_ - please show the actual, resulting HTML instead. (No one here wants to have to set up a running aspx system just to be able to reproduce your problem.)

Comment: If I'm being honest I don't understand what you're asking for? I'm new to coding, total beginner and learning. Do you want a picture of the page as it displays when opened in a web browser?

Comment: Your aspx code _produces_ HTML as its result - show that resulting HTML code, _instead of_ the aspx code. Browser -> “view page source” … In text form, not as an image. The aspx code itself is likely not relevant to the problem _at all_ (had you hard-coded the same HTML it results in, or used any other server-side language to create it, the result/problem would still be the same) - and by showing us the aspx you are making it harder for people here to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the details. I've updated the original post with the resulting HTML. Thanks!

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? https://jsfiddle.net/ocbjeaqt/ - both fields looks pretty much the same to me (testing in Chrome) with the code you have shown.

Comment: @KalenKaczor Now you've updated the question I've updated it with a _snippet_ showing the code.  It appears to work correctly!  What problem are you getting here?

Comment: I see the second input has `Type="password"` with an uppercase T. But that can't be the problem, right? I mean, the output isn't XHTML?

Comment: @Martin when I run the code the password box does not appear with the correct CSS formatting that I want, so the username and password boxes look different. Can I post an image here? It doesn't seem to let me..

Comment: @KalenKaczor Please paste the link to the screenshot and I'll add it to the question for you

Comment: @Martin just noticed that you have `input` for username and password instead of a textbox, which is how I have my code setup. I'm sure that's probably why yours works and mine does not. I can change that in my code but then I have an issue in the code behind, I'm used to getting variables from textboxes but not from an `input` field. How would I call that variable?  What would be the `username.Text` equivalent for this? Thank you!! :)

Comment: @KalenKaczor The `input` is what is ultimately rendered by ASP.Net.  Your `<asp:TextBox ... >` elements will be rendered as `input`s in the output, so you shouldn't need to change them

Comment: Ok, but your code snippet shows this:
`<div class="content">
  <h2>Sign In</h2>
  <input name="username" type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" /><br />
  <input name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" Type="password" /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" /><br />
</div>`

Comment: While my code is written as this:
`<div class="content">
                    <h2>Sign In</h2>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="username" placeholder="Username" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="password" placeholder="Password" runat="server" Type="password"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submit_click" /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMessage" runat="server" Text="Incorrect User Credentials" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                </div>`

Comment: I think I see what your comment is saying so hopefully they don't need to be changed but it seems that could be the reason to me.. it's the only difference between your snippet that works and mine that doesn't.

Comment: @KalenKaczor If you run the snippet code I embedded in your question above, you'll see that there is no problem at all with it.  I suspect the issue lies in your ASP.net implementation somehow but can't offer further advice without knowing more

Comment: @KalenKaczor A final thought - have you tried a _full refresh_ in your browser, which forces reloading of CSS?  Open your web page and push `CTRL+F5`.  This will force your most recent CSS to be loaded

Comment: @Martin I tried the page refresh, no luck. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Martin, using your code exactly as it is in the working snippet, it still does not function. If I change `<input name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" Type="password" /><br />` to `<input name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" Type="text" /><br />` it works just fine. Literally all it takes is changing `type` from `text` to `password` and it displays as in this screenshot.  https://imgur.com/cXLpAoq

Answer (score 0):

Add TextMode="Password" for password field to refer the input element as password. You  have given only id and placeholder.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
```

Comment: Read the question again: _As soon as I set the type to password the CSS style is no longer applied_. The OP knows how to make it a password type, but the CSS no longer works when it is applied

Comment: Correct, I have added {TextMode="Password"} and that is when the CSS style no longer applies to the password textbox.

Comment: Are those curly braces?

Comment: I did not use curly brackets in the code, i was using those to indicate code, should have used ` instead of {, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following *much simplified* snippet that shows the behaving oddly:

```css
input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
    height: 30px;
    border: 0;
    margin-top: 2.5vh;
    margin-left: 4.5vw;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

Look at your CSS now, particularly this line:

```
.content input[type=text], input[type=password]
```

Where the input type *is not explictly set to `text`* there is no default styling.  In addition, the selector for the password type is also wrong, it should be `.content input[type=password]`.

Have a look at this version, which includes styling for all inputs that do not have a type set using the selector `input:not([type])`:

```css
input:not([type]),
input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
    height: 30px;
    border: 0;
    margin-top: 2.5vh;
    margin-left: 4.5vw;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

Alternatively, force the display of your `Username` input to be `text` by explicitly stating it:

```
<asp:TextBox type="text" ID="username" placeholder="Username" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I had previously tried it with `.content input[type=password]` but that had the same results as my posted code.

I tried your suggestion of `input:not([type]),
input[type=text],
input[type=password]` but I still get the same result, the CSS style is no longer applied to the password textbox.